# react native push notification doesn't run in background

Tags: react-native, push-notification, localnotification, react-native-push-notification

I'm trying to implement push notifications with react native app with this plugin react-native-push-notifications. what I succeed is to get notification when app is running(in foreground), but what I'm looking to do is to get local notification when app is closed(background), not running and when I get notification to go into the app.

This is my Code -

```
  PushNotification.createChannel({
    channelId: "alarm-channel",
    channelName: "Alarm Channel",
    importance: 4,
    vibrate: true,
  });
};

const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
const handleDatePicker = (dateTime) => {
  const fireDate = dateTime;

  PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    channelId: "alarm-channel",
    title: 'title',
    id: alarmNotifData.id,
    message: 'message',
    date: fireDate ,
    soundName: "Default",
    actions: ["Snooze", "Stop Reminder"],
    importance: Importance.HIGH,
    playSound: true,
    allowWhileIdle: true,
    invokeApp: false,
    priority: "high",
    timeoutAfter: 50000,
    autoCancel: false,
    vibrate: true,
    vibration: 500,
  });
};

handleDatePicker(selectedDate);
```

Comment: If the problem is in the android environment, I had such a problem. Maybe it'll work for you. https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/2360

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to implement notifications in the background. I highly recommend adopting the `@notifee/react-native` package.

[Installation instructions](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/installation)

You can use React Native AppState to check whether or not you're currently in the foreground of the app or in the background.

For iOS, I personally like to use `AppState.current === "inactive"` since its lifecycle is always active -> inactive -> background.

For Android I use `AppState.current === "background"` since Android only has active -> background

```
// Outside of your Functional Component, Create a type called NotificationType. 
// This will make it easy for you to choose between which in app notification you send 

export enum NotificationType {
  Eating = "EATING",
  Sleeping = "SLEEPING",
}

// Notification ID is used for Android, I only need one personally
export enum NotificationID {
  DefaultID = "default",
}
```

Next, for the file you'll notify from, import AppState and notifee

```
import {AppState} from "react-native"
import notifee from "@notifee/react-native";
```

Within your app setup code create a state variable for appState and set up an AppState listener

```
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);

  // This is used as a callback function whenever AppState changes
  const handleAppStateChange = useCallback(
    (newState: any) => {
      console.log(`AppState changed to ${newState}`);
      setAppState(newState);
    },
    []
  );

  // Initial useEffect to set things up
  useEffect(() => {
    let isActive = true;
    let appStateSubscriber: NativeEventSubscription;
    const loadNavSubscriber = async () => {
      if (isActive) {
        // Adding the listener for whether the user leaves the app
        console.log(`Adding AppState event listener`);
        appStateSubscriber = AppState.addEventListener("change", 
        handleAppStateChange);
      }
    };
    loadNavSubscriber();
    
    // It's always good practice to ask the user for notification permissions
    const getNotificationPermissions = async () => {
      if (isActive) {
        const settings = await notifee.requestPermission();
      }
    };
    getNotificationPermissions();
    return () => {
      isActive = false;
      if (appStateSubscriber) appStateSubscriber.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Now Create a handleNotification method. This works for both Android and iOS

```
  const handlePushNotification = useCallback(
    async (
      enabled: boolean, // I simply pass in the appState state variable or AppState.current
      notificationID: string,
      notificationType: NotificationType
    ) => {
      // Display a notification
      if (!enabled) {
        return;
      }
      const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
        id: notificationID,
        name: "APP_NAME_TO_DISPLAY",
        visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC,
        importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
        // This adds vibration but I personally don't like vibration
        // vibration: false,
        // vibrationPattern: [100, 200, 100, 200],
      });

      if (notificationType === NotificationType.EATING) {
        await notifee.displayNotification({
          title: "Eating = YUMMY",
          body: `I love to eat food`,
          ios: { categoryId: "eating_category" },
          android: {
            channelId,
            smallIcon: "ic_icon", //read docs if you want an icon 
            importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
            pressAction: {
              id: "androidOpenApp",
              launchActivity: "default",
              launchActivityFlags: [AndroidLaunchActivityFlag.SINGLE_TOP],
            },
            actions: [
              {
                title: "Stop Eating", //this will show if you long press the notification. Read docs to set up actions 
                pressAction: {
                  id: "stop-eating",
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        });
      } else if (notificationType === NotificationType.SLEEP) {
        await notifee.displayNotification({
          title: "SLEEP - Time for bed",
          body: `It's time to go to sleep!`,
          ios: { categoryId: "sleep_category" },
          android: {
            channelId,
            smallIcon: "ic_icon",
            importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
            pressAction: {
              id: "androidOpenApp",
              launchActivity: "default",
              launchActivityFlags: [AndroidLaunchActivityFlag.SINGLE_TOP],
            },
// You may have the same actions or different ones depending on your app
            actions: [
              {
                title: "Stop Sleeping",
                pressAction: {
                  id: "stop-sleeping",
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        });
      } 
    },
    [... whatever deps you need]
  );
```

Then, somewhere in your code you can say.

```
if (nextCustomerActivity === "sleeping") {
  // Notify them that they need to go to sleep
   handlePushNotification(
// Only notify if the app is in the background
      Platform.OS === "ios" && appState === "inactive" || Platform.OS === "android" && appState === "background", 
    NotificationID.DefaultID,
      NoticationType.Sleeping
    );
} else if (nextCustomerActivity === "eating) {
  // notify them they need to start eating
handlePushNotification(
      Platform.OS === "ios" && appState === "inactive" || Platform.OS === "android" && appState === "background", // Only notify if the app is in the background
    NotificationID.DefaultID,
      NoticationType.Eating
    );
} else {
  // no need to notify
}
```

In android if you're experiencing that a new instance of your app is getting created when you open up a notification, make sure you check your `AndroidManifest.xml`. This took me hours to fix in the past.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true"
```

the whole activity in question for `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="YOUR_APP_NAME" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I've been looking for a good package for notifications for 2 days. The problem is that when I'm looking for a package on a subject I don't know, I have a hard time finding a good package. I couldn't come across Notifee while researching. Notifee looks fine. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! If this answer was sufficient, please feel free to set it as the preferred answer!

Comment: I updated it! Hopefully this helps provide more context of how to use Notifee. The instructions on the site are awesome as well

Comment: @UcheNkadi I try this but in my case i am using trigger notification (notifee) so this code doesn't work for me !!

Comment: Check this i raise another question for this.

[Notifee Trigger notification doesn't work in Lock Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76226437/notifee-trigger-notification-doesnt-work-in-lock-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Use background services to run your code when app is closed. For Android, react-native has Headless.js but to do that you need to write some native code. Unfortunately react-native has no documentation for IOS right now.

For Android : https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android

A library that does this for both IOS & Android : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-actions

Comment: Which part may I warp in so that it runs on the background? because if I wrap the PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule() then it will generate new schedule every time with new id.

Comment: @berkzel Isn't localNotificationSchedule a build to run in the background? Do you really need an extra package for this to run in the background?

Comment: Yes, localNotificationSchedule is a background service. Blogger Klik is right. But I think some devices kills background services like that for battery optimization. So creating a new service for notification system could be solution for that. Also try localNotificationSchedule again in release version of your app.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing might be due to missing dependencies in your `android\app\build.gradle` file, my issue fixed by adding this settings:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0'
    // ...
}
```

Firebase provides several services such as Firebase Functions, Firebase Messaging and Firebase Instance IDs, which are used by push notification systems. Make sure to include these dependencies

---

In addition, react-native-push-notification requires a notification channel to be specified for your push notifications. This can be done by adding specific meta-data tags inside the application tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file :

```
<application>
  <meta-data 
    android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_name"
    android:value="PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="PUSH_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL" />
  <meta-data 
    android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.notification_channel_description"
    android:value="Channel for push notification events" />
</application>
```

These meta-data tags define the name, ID, and description of your notification channel. You can learn more about notification channels from the [Android Developers guide](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels).

---

Furthermore, I've heard that it's best to provide a delay to the open link in order to ensure that the application is up and capable of handling it. However, I'm not sure if this is true, so I modified my `onNotification` in `PushNotification.configure` to add a delay to it if the app is in the foreground:

```js
onNotification: async function (notification) {
  if (notification.userInteraction) {
    const { link = null } = notification?.data || {};
    if (!link) return
    if (notification.foreground === false) {
      // The app was in the background or closed, delay the link opening
      setTimeout(() =>
        Linking.openURL(link).catch(e => console.log(e))
        , 1000);
    } else
      Linking.openURL(link).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
},
```

Please take note that I have saved the link in the notification data; you are free to modify it according to your preferences.