# Notifee Trigger notification doesn't work in Lock Screen

Tags: react-native, push-notification, android-notifications

I'm trying to implement Notifee Triggers with react native app with this plugin @notifee/react-native. what I succeed is to get notification when app is running(in foreground), but what I'm looking to do is to get local notification when device is locked (In locked device notification come with delay of 4-5 min)

This is my Code -

```
async function scheduleNotification() {
  
    const notificationDate = new Date(date);
    const notificationTime = new Date(time);

    const notificationTimestamp = notificationDate.setHours(
      notificationTime.getHours(),
      notificationTime.getMinutes(),
      0,
      0,
    );

    await notifee.createChannel({
      id: 'default',
      name: 'Default Channel',
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
    });


    // Create a time-based trigger
    const trigger = {
      type: TriggerType.TIMESTAMP,
      timestamp: notificationTimestamp,
      importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
      visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC,
    };

    await notifee.createTriggerNotification(
      {
        title: title,
        body: desciption,
        android: {
          channelId: 'default',
          actions: [snoozeAction, dismissAction],
          category: AndroidCategory.CALL,
          // importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
          fullScreenAction: {
            id: 'default',
            launchActivity: 'com.myapp.CustomActivity',
          },
          importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
          visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC,
          vibration: true,
          loopSound: true,
          sound: 'Default',
          timeoutAfter: 6000,
          vibrationPattern: [300, 500],
        },
      },
      trigger,
    );
}
```

Comment: Check for the notification permissions for your app in settings.

Comment: @Nabeel already checked and applied still not showing on lock screen

Comment: does notifee supports notifications in lockscreen? did you check their docs?

Comment: yes, they dont tell briefly about it but supports

Comment: Is your app getting killed in the background? What sort of scenario Do you have that requires a notification to run in the background? 

Are you actually looking to do remote notifications?

Comment: @Uch No, i am trying to schedule local notification and notifee provide background service for trigger notification on time when device is locked and something but in my case my device is blocking this service so, need a high priority service who dont care about power saving mode | battery optmization  ,.. like : Alarm or Reminder app

Comment: Is this issue occurring on Android or iOS or both? I think you can set a priority on Android. I set Priority to High and the default is Low Priority which isn’t what you want. 

Also make sure you download the very latest version of Notifee, it supports asking for permissions on both iOS and Android

Comment: @Uch I am making this app for Android, and as you said, set the priority high, but notifee library does not provide the function of priority.
It only gives the feature of  Importance and I checked it on high.., nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Android notification triggers will use the `WorkManager API`. Using this API for notifications does not promise exact timings for notifications, so if your application notifications are time-sensitive, you need to use the `AlarmManager API`. Notifee defaults the `alarmManager` prop on `TimestampTrigger` to `false`, causing your notifications to use less battery power (with the WorkManager API) but not giving you exact notification timings.

If your notifications are time-sensitive and require exact timing, change your code to use `alarmManager` instead, like this:

```
const trigger = {
  type: TriggerType.TIMESTAMP,
  timestamp: notificationTimestamp,
  importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
  visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC,
  alarmManager: {
     allowWhileIdle: true,
  },
};
```

Please note that your code may only require to set `alarmManager: true`, in that case you can omit the `allowWhileIdle` attribute. The allowWhileIdle option is a specific configuration for the AlarmManager API. If set to true, it allows your app to wake up the device in order to execute the task even when the device is in Doze mode. Adjust according to your needs.

Finally, I do not know what package you are using to ask your users for notification permissions. Make sure that you are requesting `alarm` permissions from your users in order to use the AlarmManager functionality.

Hope this solves your issue!